# Stop button is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to create a audio media player. In my code there is a button to stop the song.
Everything is going well but if go to another activity (for playlist or home screen) and again come back to main page stop button is not working.

```
btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (firsttime) {
                    btnplay.setText("Play");
                    mp.stop();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information if you want a specific answer.

Comment: this the what stop button is doing

Comment: May be your `firsttime` becomes false on coming back from another activity ! so did you tested it ?

Comment: firsttime is just a variable to ensure that play button has pressed atleast once  otherwise mp.stop will generate error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you set button click listener. In which phase of activity life cycle (onCreate or onResume). I think the problem is with the activity life cycle. If you put the btn click listener in onCreate please replace it from onCreate and put in onResume method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// use this method rather than stop
mp.reset();
mp.release();
```

Comment: It will stop the song. i just wanted that song play continue but stop button also work on same song  when we come back on this activity again